# How to disable sessions, cookies and autologins on dektrium-user extension?

Tags: php, session, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm triying to do the same someone asked here:

[How to disable sessions, cookies and auto login in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738482/how-to-disable-sessions-cookies-and-auto-login-in-yii2)

but I'm using this module:

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

I know how to do this with current user classes in Yii but found nothing related in dektrium's documentation.

Using basic app template.

Comment: So you want to build a stateless API using yii2-user?

Comment: @Mihai P. Yes, by definition is what I'm asking (I think so).

Comment: did you find solution?