# Yii2: How to stop cookies from being loaded from the start

Tags: cookies, yii

I haven't found where the yii framework starts cookies, but by EU right I have to first get the visitors consent before they can be used.
So, does anyone know where I can set it to this kind of behavior (or deactivate them) :

- load website without cookies
- ask if visitor consents to the use of cookies
- load cookies
- remember decision

Comment: [albertborsos/yii2-gdpr-cookie-consent](https://github.com/albertborsos/yii2-gdpr-cookie-consent) might do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

See here [How to disable sessions, cookies and auto login in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738482/how-to-disable-sessions-cookies-and-auto-login-in-yii2?rq=1)

But also consider that this case is more Business Logic (Code in your Controller) what cookies and personal information you want you to keep and store in your web project. Few cookies like Session PHP Id to identify which user (Anonymus User) request in your server is not a problem I think. Also, GDPR exists to protect personal info in E.U. Store user's data (by your Controller/Action through Models) only if you have their consent

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't answer and thanks for the info.